# Call /env on Spring cloud config client side, password property shows " portal.db.password=*** "

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

My config file on remote git repo:

myapp-uat.properties:

```
portal.db.userName=allen
portal.db.password=allen1235
```

I could load this file on client side, and I want save these properties by call /env, but get portal.db.password=***.

I wonder if I could get real value (portal.db.password=allen1235) by adding some properties in client config file or some other methods. Hope for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is the default sanitized keywords for `/env` endpoint.

```
endpoints:  
  env:   
    keys-to-sanitize: password,secret,key,token,.*credentials.*,vcap_services
```

You can override the below property without `password` by defining below in your `application.yml/properties`.

```
endpoints:  
  env:   
    keys-to-sanitize: secret,key,token,.*credentials.*,vcap_services
```